# Update twenty twelve theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to update couple of things on my website design using wordpress. I use the twenty twelve theme. so if anyone could please advise how to do the following updates:

1- Move the pic to the top of the page before the page title, so that it would be the same size but just position it on the top.

2- Resize the title to be with bigger font and increase the font of the second title as well "Anabaptist Believers....."

3- Change the color of this subtitle "Anabaptist ...." to be blue the same color as the big title and make it boldface as well.

Comment: You're asking in the wrong place. Your question doesn't include what you've tried

Comment: I'm not very familiar with word press. I know that I need to update the style.css. I've been able to solve the third pint, but I don't want to do wrong things with the first two, that's why I'm trying to ask experts here if they can assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 you need to move:

```
<?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

above the `<nav>` tag in the `header.php` file.

For #2 you need to increase the `.site-header h1` `font-size` to a higher number.

For #3 you need to change the colour to: `color: #084b8a;`

EDIT:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <hgroup>
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
    </hgroup>
    <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
        <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->


</header>
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

```
<?php if(is_front_page()) :
    echo '<img src="">';                    
endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. 2 and 3 worked fine!!! Thank you. But for the first one I've moved this `<?php $header_image = get_header_image();
  if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
  <?php endif; ?> ` before the nav tag and it's still the same

Comment: I have edited in the way the header looks on my site, which has the banner image above the navigation bar

Comment: Thanks, but I've just tried it on my website and its not moving anywhere :/ I don't know why

Comment: That image, is it a banner for the whole website or a featured image on that page? (And different pages will have different images?

Comment: it's a featured image on the home page only

Comment: Okay I have edited it again try that replace the empty image tag with a link to your image. Put that code into the header.phpfile just above the nav tag.

Comment: Thanks. it worked! but there is a strange thing happening. Although I deleted this part `<?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>` the pic is still appearing! So now it's appearing twice, one above and one below, I don't know why this is happening? I'm very thankful if you could please advise. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to remove the image from the page itself.